# Get all boolean comparisons from vectors with different lengths in R

Tags: r, vector, boolean

I've two vectors with different lengths and want to get all the occurrences of the first one in the second one.

I've tried:

```r
vec <- c("jan-fev-mar", "abr-mai-jun", "jul-ago-set")

vec2 <- c("jan-fev-mar", "abr-mai-jun", "jul-ago-set", "out-nov-dez", "jan-fev-mar", "abr-mai-jun", "jul-ago-set", "out-nov-dez")

# It returns: TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
vec %in% vec2
```

I expect to get all the occurrences of vec on vec2, like: TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE

Comment: Try `vec2 %in% vec` instead

Comment: omegalul, ty dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vec %in% vec2` returns `TRUE` for each element in `vec` if there is a match in all elements of `vec2`. The result is a logical vector of length equal to `length(vec)`.

It seems you want `vec2 %in% vec`, which returns:

```r
vec2 %in% vec
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

You could interpret it like the following:

`(vec2 %in% vec)[1]`: There is a match of `vec2[1]` (= "jan-fev-mar") in `vec`? `TRUE`

`(vec2 %in% vec)[2]`: There is a match of `vec2[2]` (= "abr-mai-jun") in `vec`? `TRUE`

...

`(vec2 %in% vec)[8]`: There is a match of `vec2[8]` (= "out-nov-dez") in `vec`? `FALSE`